# React Jest Mock a variable used inside a component while rendering the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a test case where I need to render a component and check the rendered component afterwards. This rendered value depends on a variable used inside a component.

**Triangle.tsx:**

```
export const Triangle = ({
     prop1,
      prop2
    }: Props): JSX.Element => {
      const [variable1] = useVarState();
      if(!variable1) {
        return <></>;
      return (<div></div>);
```

**TriangleTest.tsx:**

```
describe('Testing component', () => {
          test('Main Elements', () => {
            const prop1 = jest.fn();
            const prop2 = undefined;
        
            const container = render(
              <Triangle
                prop1={prop1}
                prop2={prop2}
              />
            );
        
            const triangle = container.container.querySelector(
              '.Triangle'
            );
            expect(triangle).not.toBeNull();
        }
    }
```

How can I mock the value of variable? `useVarState` returns a map based on a `useContext`.

Comment: You _can't_ directly mock it, it's a local variable inside the function scope. Did you consider mocking the _hook_? Also as far as we can tell the test would never pass as, even fixing the syntax errors, neither return sets a class.